# How to solve Longest Increasing Subarray in Scala functionally?

Tags: scala, collections

We can write an imperative solution for [Longest Increasing Subarray](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-continuous-increasing-subsequence) like this :

```scala
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = {
  var len = 0
  var left = 0
  for (i <- nums.indices) {
    if (i > 0 && nums(i) <= nums(i - 1)) left = i
    len = math.max(len, i - left + 1)
  }
  len
}
```

Now I want to write a functional solution without loops and indices that may return also all increasing subarrays.

```scala
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = {

  @annotation.tailrec
  def spanIncreasing(xs: List[Int], result: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = xs match {
    case x :: tail if result.isEmpty || x > result.head => spanIncreasing(tail, x :: result)
    case _ => (result.reverse, xs)
  }

  @annotation.tailrec
  def dropNotIncreasing(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
    case x :: y :: tail if x >= y => dropNotIncreasing(y :: tail)
    case _ => xs
  }

  def step(pair: (List[Int], List[Int])): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
    spanIncreasing(pair._1, Nil) match {
      case (increasing, tmp) => dropNotIncreasing(tmp) -> increasing
    }
  }

  def increasingSubarrays(xs: List[Int]): Iterator[List[Int]] = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) Iterator(Nil) else
      Iterator.iterate(xs -> List.empty[Int])(step).drop(1).map(_._2).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
  }

  increasingSubarrays(nums.toList).map(_.size).max
}
```

The solution is working but looks monstrous. I guess using `fold` or `unfold` instead of `iterate` will not simplify the solution significantly ... How would you simplify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this fp enough?

```
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = 
    (nums zip nums.tail).scanLeft(1){ 
        case(r, (p, n)) => if(n > p) r + 1 else 1 
    }.max
```

Or

```
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = 
    (nums zip nums.tail).foldLeft((1, 1)){ 
        case((r, m), (p, n)) => if(n > p) (r+1, m.max(r+1)) else (1, m) 
    }._2
```

BTW: If **fp style means tedious**, I **do not** want it at all.

Note: The above solutions assuming that `nums` is not empty, just as the problem [Longest Increasing Subarray](https://leetcode.cn/problems/longest-continuous-increasing-subsequence/?utm_source=LCUS&utm_medium=ip_redirect&utm_campaign=transfer2china) says. But it is easy to make it works for empty array, and **keep one line**.

Comment: Wow ! It's actually one-liner :)) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note to myself: remember this `nums zip nums.tail` technique to handle adjacent array elements

Comment: @Michael note that (if I understand it correctly) this will fail on empty arrays/collections.

Comment: @GuruStron Oh, thanks for spotting this. You are right : `tail` fails on empty sequences. Interesting, that this solution is accepted on Leetcode anyway :))

Comment: @GuruStron The problem itself assuming that nums is not empty.

Comment: @Michael Leetcode one has constraint of passed collection being non-empty. I was talking more about general case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the cleanest option but I would argue using intermediate aggregator and matching looks less monstrous then provided one (if I have not made some stupid mistake along the way):

```scala
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = {
  
  // can use tuple instead, but prefer meaningful names
  case class Agg(val prev: Int, val maxLen: Int = 0, val curLen: Int = 0)

  @annotation.tailrec
  def inner(seq: Seq[Int], agg: Agg): Agg = seq match {
    case head +: next if head <= agg.prev => inner(next, Agg(head, agg.maxLen max agg.curLen, 1))
    case head +: next => inner(next, Agg(head, agg.maxLen, agg.curLen + 1))
    case Nil => Agg(0, agg.maxLen max agg.curLen)
  }

  inner(nums.toSeq, Agg(Int.MinValue)).maxLen
}
```

**UPD**

> I wanted a more generic solution to get all increasing subarrays first

This can be achieved for example with `foldl` and list of list aggregate:

```scala
val subArrs = nums
   .foldLeft(List.empty[List[Int]])((agg, curr) => agg match {
      case (head :: tail) :: next if curr > head => (curr :: head :: tail) :: next
      case _ => List(curr) :: agg
    })
    .map(_.reverse) // optional for original order
    .reverse // optional for original order
```

And then max length can be calculated as:

```
maxLength = subArrs
    .map(_.length)
    .maxOption
    .getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Thanks ! The solution is nice and not monstrous at all. Frankly, I wanted a more generic solution to get all increasing subarrays first and then compute the max size if needed. However I did not ask it clearly.

Comment: @Michael Glad if it helped! _"I wanted a more generic solution"_ - it can be achieved by changing the aggregate. Or via approach in the update.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the generic solution. Looks really nice by the way.

Comment: BTW, I guess case `case Nil => List(curr) :: Nil` is redundant because `case _ => List(curr) :: agg` already handles it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got. Don't know if you consider it "monstrous" ...

```
val it = nums
  .iterator
  .scanLeft(Option.empty[Int] -> Option.empty[Int]) { case (p, x) => p._2 -> Some(x) }
  .flatMap { 
     case (_, None) => Nil
     case (a, Some(b)) if a.exists(_ >= b) => Seq(None, Some(b))
     case (_, b) => Seq(b)
  }

Iterator.continually { 
  it.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.toSeq 
}.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: Thanks. Not monstrous but looks more complicated than the imperative solution :((

Comment: It's a matter of what you are used to I would say. 10 years ago pretty much anything written in scala looked "more complicated" to me than imperative solutions :) 
Now I can barely read the latter :D

Comment: BTW, your imperative solution is simple because it is only looking for for max len. If you were to enhance it to return a lazy iterator of all increasing subsequences that are being constructed on demand, it would become quite a bit more complicated ...

Comment: I agree. The lazy iterator is better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using a tail-recursive function that computes the wanted length with a sliding window (left & right indexes of the input Array):

```
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: Array[Int]): Int = {
  val sz = nums.length
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: Int, r: Int, rPrev: Int, maxLen: Int): Int = {
    if (r == sz) maxLen
    else {
      if (nums(r) <= nums(rPrev))
        loop(r, r+1, r, maxLen)
      else
        loop(l, r+1, r, Math.max(maxLen, r-l+1))
    }
  }
  if (sz <= 1) sz
  else loop(0, 1, 0, 1)
}
```

Another tail-recursive version via the usual `head::tail` `List` deconstructions:

```
def findLengthOfLCIS(nums: List[Int]): Int = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(ls: List[Int], prev: Int, len: Int, maxLen: Int): Int = ls match {
    case Nil => maxLen
    case curr :: rest =>
      if (curr <= prev)
        loop(rest, curr, 1, maxLen)
      else
        loop(rest, curr, len + 1, Math.max(maxLen, len + 1))
  }
  if (nums.isEmpty) 0
  else loop(nums.tail, nums.head, 1, 1)
}
```